# C++ pass a non const string by reference with default value

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, constants, pass-by-reference

So I am working on a codebase where this someFunc is called at a lot of places and I can't afford to change it by adding this new variable at all places where this function is called. And that too when that variable is not needed at all the place where someFunc is called.

So I have a requirement where I need to have a function definition having a string which is pass by reference and we are able to mutate the value of the same.

- Pass by reference: because that string variable is used by the caller
- Default value : Because this func is called at lot of place, can't change everywhere.
- Non const : Because I want to mutate it

This is what I have tried :

```
ExceptionClass ClassName::someFunc(int a, float b, map<int, string> c, const string &d = "")
```

The problem with this approach is I am unable to change the value of d inside my function. Getting following error :

[image]

How do I use something that fulfills my requirement?

Comment: So what is the point of modifying `d` if it is just the default temporary? (Also I assume you mean `d` not `c` in "_I am unable to change the value of c inside my function_".)

Comment: okay so I am working on a codebase where this someFunc is called at a lot of places and I can't afford to change it by adding this new variable at all places where this function is called. ANd that too when that variable is not needed at all the place where `someFunc` is called

Comment: How about an overload taking 3 parameters instead of 4: `ExceptionClass someFunc(int a, float b, map<int, string> c) { std::string defaultVal = ""; return someFunc(a, b, std::move(c), defaultValue);}` Note that it's weird to have an out parameter that is optional. If this is not an out parameter, you should pass the parameter by rvalue reference or by value; both allow you to specify a default value in addition to not preventing modifications of the object passed as parameter.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain how you want the function to actually work when used. When a string is passed in, the passed string object will actually be changed, or the function will just make changes to a local copy without changing the original string? When no string is passed and the default argument is used, that means the changes the function body made should just be discarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the *equivalent* behavior that you are describing by using a separate overload instead of a default value:

```
class ClassName {
public:
  ExceptionClass someFunc(int a, float b, map<int, string> c, string &d);
  ExceptionClass someFunc(int a, float b, map<int, string> c) {
    string d = "";
    return someFunc(a, b, c, d);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning "" as default argument makes no sense. If you are modifying the argument then those changes seem to have some value and that would be lost with a string literal.

I can think of two ways that could make sense:

```
static string someFuncDefault = "";
ExceptionClass ClassName::someFunc(int a, float b, map<int, string> c, string &d = someFuncDefault);
```

or

```
ExceptionClass ClassName::someFunc(int a, float b, map<int, string> c, optional<reference_wrapper<string>> d_opt = {});
```

The first case would have a default argument that persists across function calls. So modifications from one call will change the default use for the next call.

The second makes the string optional but in a way the code can check if it was passed or not and behave accordingly. No point modifying the string if it wasn't passed along.

But really, why don't you have 2 functions? One with 3 and one with 4 arguments?

Comment: `One with 3 and one with 4 arguments` was implemeting this only rn, but the problem with your first approach is the variable will remain forever in the memory until the process goes down

Answer (score -1):

Why using `const` if you want to mutate the string. Try this version:

```
ExceptionClass ClassName::someFunc(int a, float b, map<int, string> c, string &d)
```

Comment: and what about default value? the main purpose of giving it the default value was this function is called at a lot of place and I don't want to add a new variable at all those places where its called. BTW I didn't downvote

Comment: You didn't mention the default value is your requirement

Comment: @MohammadRifatArefin Not a good practice to "hide" this kind of info in the title, but the info is there: *"C++ pass a string by reference **with default value** and non const"*

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the title, totally my bad!